# How to plot right ascension with time of the retrograde motion of mars?

Tags: solar-system, positional-astronomy, retrograde-orbit

Measure the right ascension, declination of mars and sun. plot the variation of right ascension with time.

Comment: Would [astronomy.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: No.  There is no question here, just a request.  @123Vega Please clarify what your question is.  Note that we aren't going to do your homework for you.  You need to measure the right ascension of mars and plot the variation with time.  We also expect you to do basic work first, like know how to plot a graph. I've voted to close, as in its current state, it is unsuitable for [Astronomy.se]